# Complex Query for Displaying comments based on friends added

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very big problem with my website. I have a form, more like a text box used in submitting comments, that not the problem. The problem is displaying the comments. I want to *display comments based on the friends a user added* like the way facebook, twitter does.

I have 3 tables:`photo_tb`, `comment_tb`, `friendship_tb`.

The `friendship_tb` contains columns **name**, **friend**. *name* stores your email and *friend stores* the  email of the person you add....

I need the `photo_tb` to get the picture of the person making the comment and I use a mysql join successfully.

In my `comment_tb`...i get the email of the person making the comment in my commentname column and comment made by the person...

I want to to show comment by ffriendship like if Mr A adds Mr B and Mr c..when Mr A logs on he should only get comments by both Mr B and Mr c and his comments doe not comments from Mr G or H.

This is what i have so far

```
SELECT
     comment_tb.comment_id
   , comment_tb.comname
   , comment_tb.comment
   , comment_tb.time
   , photo_tb.name
   , photo_tb.photo
   , friendship.name
   , friendship.member
FROM comment_tb, photo_tb, friendship
WHERE
        comment_tb.comname=photo_tb.name
    and friendship.name = colname
```

The colname is a variable for MM_Username ,the session variable when you log in is meant to display comments related to you.

The sql statement attaches the picture to each comment name successfully but doesn't limit the comment to friends added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `and friendship.member = comment_tb.comname`.

BTW, it would be nice if the column names in your SQL matches what you said in the description. I'm just guessing that `friendship.member` is what you called `friend` in the text.

Comment: Tried it ..But am getting an empty query.please help me and you are right friendship.member  is the friend column.Please help me.Thank you.sorry for replying late

Comment: Okay its working...but its displaying comments made by Mr A to Mr C when Mr C didnt add Mr A ....thanks

Comment: Is there a row in `friendship` with name = Mr A and member = Mr C? That's not a problem with this query, that's some other problem with your app.

Comment: No there is no row in friendship...I think the problem am having is displaying comment for each users maybe the colname is not working well

Comment: The query is perfectly okay because i changed the friendship.name = into a email address existing and i got a good query and also tried another email not existing...i didnt get any query..please help me its my session variable that is the problem

Comment: That's a completely different problem. Since you haven't shown how you  set colname, how can we possibly help you? You should probably accept my answer and ask a new question for that part.